# Adding some noise to a text

Tags: string, noise-generator

I wonder if there is any known algorithm/strategy to add some noise to a text string (for instance, adding a random sequence of characters every now and then or something similar).

I don't want to completely destroy the text just to make it slightly unusable. Also, I'm not interested in reversing back the changes, I can just recreate the original text from the sources I used to create it in the first place if needed.

Of course, a very basic algorithm for doing this could be easyly implemented but probably somebody has already created a somewhat sophisticated algorithm for this. If a Java implementation of something like this is available even better.

Comment: What is the intention behind making the text noisy?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net and you need some random bytes maybe try the [GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getbytes.aspx) method from the rngcryptoprovider. Nice n random. You could also use it to help in selection random positions to update.